# What does mean, when find() and insert() cursors returned =1

Tags: php, mongodb

Good day.
I used php driver and want to know what does mean `1` returned by `insert()`

```
$collection->insert(array("book"=>"Freedom"));
echo $collection;
```

=>1
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, you really need to read documents before asking a question

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php#refsect1-mongocollection.insert-returnvalues